# JPA2.0/Hibernate - Transaction issue with hibernate's EmptyInterceptor

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, interceptor

I am using JPA2.0 in my application with Hibernate. For audit logging purposes, I am using Hibernate's '**org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor**'. My configuration looks like below:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistenceUnitName="EvolutionPU"
        p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:persistence.xml"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
                  <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor">com.xxx.audit.interceptor.AuditLogInterceptor</prop>                          
            </props>
        </property>     

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

**Audit Logging Interceptor which Implements EmptyInterceptor:**

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public AuditLogInterceptor() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        //My code for audit logging
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        //My code for audit logging
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) throws CallbackException {
        //My code for audit logging
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My service method looks like below:**

```
@Service("mySerivceImpl")
    public class MySerivceImpl{

        @Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
        public void saveEntity(EntityVO entityVO) {

        }
    }
```

Notice that I have annotated service method with **@Transactional**.

Whenever this method is called, I capture old and new entity values in AuditLogInterceptor and try to save those into my History table using HistoryDAO.

But while saving audit data using HistoryDAO in AuditLogInterceptor, I get the issue:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
        at com.adp.evolution.dao.audit.AuditDaoImpl.saveAuditData(AuditDaoImpl.java:436)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor759.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Even though I am in a transaction (that is there is the service method), why this AuditLogInterceptor need another transaction? Any Idea?

Comment: Why are reinventing the wheel? Use Hibernate Envers (which is included in Hibernate 3.5+), and handles auditing automatically.

Comment: Thanks for response. I already analyzed 'Hibernate Envers' but this does not fit as per my requirement. So I have to reinvent the wheel :)